# (Galaxy Note 1) Can I use custom ROMs and Recoverys made for the GT-N7000 on a GT-N7000B?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note

The GT-N7000B is the Samsung Galaxy Note 1 sold in Thailand and Australia.

[Wikipedia: Note 1 Variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Note_%28original%29#Variants)

I am wondering, if I can use custom Recoverys and ROMs like Cyanogenmod made for the International GT-N7000 on the GT-N7000B.
Specfically I am interested in [this one](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-note/development/rom-t2938649).

Answer (score 0):

It worked for the Nightowl ROM.
Now the device just identifies as a GT-N7000.
I reporter this to the developer and he added the info to the OP.